# Python- Error on abs value return

Tags: python

Any help will be appreciated. Below is the code:

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    if type(n) == int or type(n) == float:
        return abs 
    else:
        return Nope
```

Comment: use `return abs(n)`. And what is `return Nope` ? What do you intend to return if not `int` or `float`

Answer (score 2):

The error is because abs is a built-in function but in your code, it is not returning any value. You need to change **abs** to **abs(n)**. The other problem is that **Nope** is no keyword.

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
if type(n) == int or type(n) == float:
    return abs(n) 
else:
    return "Nope"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    if type(n) == int or type(n) == float:
        return abs(n)
    else:
        # return Nope does not work
        # do something else
```

Another way to do this:

```
def distance_from_zero(n):
    try:
        abs(n)
    except TypeError:
        print("n is not int or float")
        # do something else
        # you can raise OR pass and handle the error yourself
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better in this way:

```py
if 1 is True:  # Not if 1 == True

if 1 is False:   # Not if 1 == False

if type(1) is int:  # Not if type(1) == int
```